# Figuring Animate() Slide Up / Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, slide

I have a DIV tag which is the hover() trigger. However, I cannot change this div`s setting, css and etc.

In this situation, if I want to have a animate effect, slide down from the bottom of this trigger div tag. How can I do it?

I tried and create a Div absolute area on the top of the trigger Div, it didnt work. Please help and advice.

HTML

```
<div id="trigger" style="width:100px; height:100px; border:#000 solid 1px;"></div> //This is the trigger div
<div id="target" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#000; position:absolute;"></div> // This is the thing I gonna slide down
```

JS

```
$('#trigger').hover(function(){
    target = $('#target');
    trigger = $('#trigger');


  ///create a area can hide Target before slide down
    target.wrapAll('<div style="border:#000 solid 1px; position: absolute; top: '+ trigger.offset().top + trigger.height() +'; left:" '+ trigger.offset().left  +'; width: '+trigger.width() +'; height: '+ trigger.height()  +'; ">')  
     .css({ top: -target.height(), left: 0  })
     .animate({top: 0 });

      }, function(){})
```

Comment: Shouldn't the trigger be what the hover event is attached to?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? (I've added three properties to the trigger div, a relative position and a z-index which forces it to be on top of the black box. Then I gave the div a background color so it obscures the black box.)

I can't help but think there is a cleaner way to do this though.

http://jsfiddle.net/bUcZg/

Code:

HTML

```
<div id="trigger" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#FFF; position:relative; z-index:1; border:#000 solid 1px;position:relative;"></div> 
<div id="target" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#000; position:absolute;"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
target = $('#target');
trigger = $('#trigger');


///create a area can hide Target before slide down
target.wrap('<div style="border:#000 solid 1px; position: absolute; top: ' +     trigger.offset().top + trigger.height() + '; left:" ' + trigger.offset().left + '; width: ' + trigger.width() + '; height: ' + trigger.height() + '; ">').css({
top: -target.height(),
left: 0
})

trigger.hover(function() {
    target.animate({
        top: 0
    });

}, function() {})​
```

Comment: I sorry, it works! However, I want the black div on the back of the trigger div, is this possible?

Comment: thank you very much. If not change the trigger div, position into absolute, this will not work.....